# Append all rows from multiple workbooks into singe workbook template

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks with the same structure, 1st row of heading and the n-rows of data/text (in total I have 5 columns, n differs from workbook to workbook). I'm looking to a code that can take all the workbooks data and combine them in a single excel workbook with 1 row of heading and then (n x number of workbooks) rows. Do you have any idea of a code that does something like this? Thanks.

I'm using this code here:

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\myfolder\comments"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:G10")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

But here I manually input the range A2:G10, the problem with this approach is that I get missing rows if a worksheet has less the 10 rows. I would have to write A2:G(count last row).

I found the code here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Comment: Ok, so what code have you tried? What are you working on? Please include that in your question if that's what you need help with.

Comment: You need to do some groundwork and try writing some code that'll force you to ask some more questions - are the books all in the same folder? Are they all the same file extension? Do you need all sheets from all books? Can you provide some sample data because the description is a bit vague?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Alla workbooks have same extension (.xlsx) and are in the same foder. I only need the first worksheet per each workbook. The difficulties are that I should write something that recognizes which is the last filled row of the template to do the append

Comment: `Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` that will give you the last row for column A.

Answer (score 1):

With your updated question and a variant of Damian's comment you can come up with this:

At this point:

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
   Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:G10")
End With
```

You can find and use the last row like so:

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
   Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems working perfectly fine. Just one last thing. Now I get as output an excel file with all the rows from all the workbooks (1st worksheet) and is fine. What if I want to copy-paste all these rows into another template that has first row as headline and is separated with freezed panels? This would be just to maintain the format of the template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This woulb be an improved way to do the code you posted:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Basic_Example_1()

    MemorySave True

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    Dim MyPath As String: MyPath = "C:\Users\myfolder\comments\"
    'you can add the slash when defining the path.

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    Dim FilesInPath As String: FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet: Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    Dim BaseLastRow As Long: BaseLastRow = 1

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    'Instead of filling an array, use this loop to import the rows
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        ImportData MyPath & FilesInPath, BaseWks
        BaseLastRow = BaseWks.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

ExitSub:
    MemorySave False

End Sub
Private Sub ImportData(WorkbookPath As String, BaseWks As Worksheet, BaseLastRow As Long)

    'The first iteration will copy the headers, after that, it won't
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    If BaseLastRow = 1 Then
        FirstRow = 1
    Else
        FirstRow = 2
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WorkbookPath, False, True)
    With wb.Sheets(1)

        'check the lastrow on the import workbook
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'if the importworkbook has more than 1 row, then copy the Range A:G
        If LastRow > 1 Then
            .Range("A" & FirstRow & ":G" & LastRow).Copy
            BaseWks.Range("A" & BaseLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

    End With

    'Close the importworkbook without saving
    wb.Close False

End Sub
Sub MemorySave(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not (isOn)
End Sub
```